# How to get absolute path to public_html folder

Tags: php, absolute-path

I'm a little confused about absolute paths when searching in the questions. I have a `php` project that includes a `Header.php` file which is the header for first level `php` files. To avoid adding another header, I want to make that work for the inner levels, too. For example use it in a `php` file that is included in another folder of project.
To do this, I wana get the absoute path to my `public_html` folder and use that in my `Header.php`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` at the start.

```
include('/header.php');
```

This will always include the `header.php` from the `root` folder.

Comment: I might be wrong here but won't this be dependent on the type of server the code running on? Will this work consistently across Windows and Linux? For that matter, won't it also require hard-coding paths to the files from root which will very likely be different across dev and live environments?

Comment: Yes. Thats right. For that case we can use variable to set the separator.

Comment: `Windows` works fine with '/' as the directory separator in 'paths'.

Answer (score 1):

You can got the absolute path of your current script file by this way :

```
$absolute_path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

You can see all of the Magic constants here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: this is the same as doing ____DIR____

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me in different servers, so had to write the following function:

```
echo  "public_html absolute path:".public_html();
function public_html() {
  $path=getcwd();
  if (!strpos($path,'public_html')) $path=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $awords= explode('/', $path); 
  $public_html="";
  foreach ($awords as  $word)   {
     $public_html.=$word."/";
     if ($word=='public_html') break;
  }
return  substr($public_html,0,-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']